# Setting SAGA folder for QGIS with OS X for macports install?

Tags: qgis, installation, saga, osx, qgis-2.6

I am trying to get the toolbox to work in QGIS 2.6, but I keep getting an error message that SAGA is not properly configured. After much digging, I finally found I can set the SAGA folder in Processing > Options > Providers > SAGA. I installed SAGA with macports. The saga_cmd executable is in my /opt/local/bin folder, but setting this as my folder does not fix the problem. I continue to get the error message.

Does anyone know how I can configure QGIS to find my saga installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [QGIS: 17.8. Running an external algorithm](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/processing/first_saga_alg.html):

> Instead, you must install SAGA and make sure that the SAGA folder is in PATH, so it can be called from the console (just open a console and type saga_cmd to check it)

It is for Linux, but it is the same for Mac OS X: can you use `saga_cmd` in the terminal ?
.

If not, you need to fix your PATH variable or you can try to modify the script **SagaUtils.py** (.../python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaUtils.py) used by the processing module to find the Saga folder installation and execute the algorithms on this basis:

```py
def findSagaFolder():
    folder = None
    if isMac():
        testfolder = os.path.join(QgsApplication.prefixPath(), 'bin')
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(testfolder, 'saga_cmd')):
           folder = testfolder
    else:
        testfolder = '/usr/local/bin'
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(testfolder, 'saga_cmd')):
            folder = testfolder
```

isMac() is for the [KingChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) version  where `saga_cmd` and the libraries are in the Application bundle.

All the other functions of SagaUtils.py use this resulting Saga path.

In my case, for example, I installed `saga_cmd`  in /Users/me/saga/bin/saga_cmd which is in my PATH and I can use Saga in the masters versions of [Larry Shaffer](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/)  (no Saga installed in the application bundle)

Comment: Yes, I can see saga_cmd in the console and I have /opt/local/bin added to my path and in SAGA folder. I am going to try your trick with SagaUtils.py right now. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a SagaUtils.py on my system. So now I'm going to try the King Chaos binary and see if that does it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The King Chaos build works for me. Its a shame the macports version can't build with out of the box SAGA support.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of gene works also for SAGA installations via homebrew.

Here are the specific changes made in `findSagaFolder()` to upgrade SAGA to version 2.2.2 in QGIS 2.14. Note that hombrew installations are always placed in `/usr/local/Cellar/`.

```
# testfolder = os.path.join(QgsApplication.prefixPath(), 'bin')
testfolder = '/usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis/2.2.2/bin'
```