# Error adding MrSID raster layer to QGIS for Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite)

Tags: qgis, raster, error, mac, mrsid

I want to add a MrSID layer to QGIS (version 2.6.1) with a computer running Mac OS X Yosemite. I installed QGIS through macports from the terminal and all python packages through macports, as well. I have been googling the problem and have tried to install all kinds of packages that MrSID may be dependent on, but it still doesn't work. This is the error it prompts:

> "/Users/jordi_pages/Downloads/LT_LiDAR_Sample_Data/Dallas_11SDK.sid is not a supported raster data source"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that there are many problems with the Macports version of QGIS ([setting SAGA folder for QGIS with OS X macports install](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136741/setting-saga-folder-for-qgis-with-os-x-macports-install), [QGIS Semi-automatic classification plugin install error on OS X 10.10: matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132574/qgis-semi-automatic-classification-plugin-install-error-on-os-x-10-10-matplotli), [How to use grass.script in MacOS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116267/how-to-use-grass-script-in-macos),...). So my question is why use this version ?

You need to add [MrSID driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mrsid.html) support into GDAL ( [How to add MrSID support into GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/TutorialMrSid)) with the LizardTech's decoding software development kit (DSDK) which is not free and it seems to me that you should ask the question on the [MacPorts support lists](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/MailingLists).

The vast majority of Mac OS X users use the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) version of QGIS where everything is compiled. You download and install the [GDAL framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) and after you can do the same thing with the  ECW plugin, the MrSID plugin, the FileGDB plugin, the GeoPDF plugin and the GRASS plugin, any more or any less and it works with the Apple Python and the Mac OS X libraries (in /usr/bin).

Another solution is to use the [Homebrew osgeo4mac](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac) version of Larry Shaffer or other [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) versions (installed in /usr/local/) (look at [Installation: QGIS on Maverick](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80872/2581))

Nothing to do with MacPorts that reinstalls all in /opt/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will try to uninstall the version I installed with MacPorts and install Qgis with KyngChaos.

Comment: Great! I have installed the kynchaos version and it works perfectly!! Thanks again!